# Doc4j Struts2 Action OutOfMemoryError

Tags: struts2, docx4j, tomcat8

I am having an Action class in struts2 application and i want to display a docx file to the user. 
When i load the file with InputStream the file opens without problem

```
fileStream = new DataInputStream(
          new FileInputStream("d:/deleme/sample.docx"));
```

The file of docx is about 26Kb and 7 pages.
but when i add the following statement in Action

```
   WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage =
                WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new FileInputStream(new java.io.File("d:/deleme/sample.docx")));
```

with no other modification to the previews code tomcat crashes with

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

How can i work docx with an action (google did not helped at all)

Comment: How much PermGen space does Tomcat have?  Give it some more ... I suspect the issue here is not the size of the docx file, but the large number of classes JAXB  has to load to represent the Open XML schemas.

Comment: I have try with a very simple docx document with only a line of characters. The tomcat works very well with hibernate and database.

Comment: That's my point, exactly.  Doesn't matter whether docx file is a single line, or 50 pages.  The permgen space is being consumed by the library itself. Configure tomcat to make it bigger.